# Github action download image

Tags: github, download, github-actions

I would like to make sure that using git actions, the possibility of being able to download an image and be able to save it in a folder in the github repository.

I've tried a similar thing, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Can you give me a hand, do you think it can be done?

Error:
[image]

Code:

```
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
name: Scrape File
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        name: Check out current commit
          
      - uses: suisei-cn/actions-download-file@v1
        id: downloadfile
        name: Download the file
        with:
          url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Meet_Truffle%21.jpg/440px-Meet_Truffle%21.jpg"
          target: assets
          auto-match: true
```

What I would like to do is that periodically, for example once a day, start a script in js which should analyze a web page and then take a specific image.

Comment: Why are you setting `auto-match: true`, overriding the default behaviour, given that you _aren't_ passing Markdown containing a link as the `url`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: You're right, I took it off, the script is fine now.
How can I save it?

Comment: What do you mean "save it"? Where? If you want it in the actual repo, as your question suggests, you'd have to make a _commit_, but that doesn't seem like a wise move. Maybe look into storing it in a file bucket or as a build artefact.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Should I do a git add., Git commit and push?

Comment: If you want to push the file to the repository, you need to commit and push it in the workflow, yes.